# Read undifined variable out of json file

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i am right now trying to program a Discord bot currencysytem that is saved in a .json file. How its saved looks like this:

```
"<userid>" : <currency>, "userid" : <currency>, ...
```

And i try to get the data out of it looks like this:

```
const currency = require('../currency.json');
    let fs = require('fs')
    let an = message.author.id

    message.channel.send(currency.{an}); // !!here I need help!!
```

In the line where i wrote "// !!I need help here!! i want to use the variable "an" and the visuial studio code doesnt get it...
Does anyone has a solution to my problem pls help me. Thx you <3

Comment: @Joe: Isn't that what the OP is already doing?

Comment: is there an error in your console?
try `message.channel.send(currency[an]);` I don't think `.{}` is valid.